# Get Tkinter to process Arrow Key Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, tkinter, keyboard-events

(I drastically simplified my code now so you should also be able to run it.)
Like I said in the previous version of this question, I am trying to get tkinter to process arrow key strokes. The following code produces a grid of $-signs with one I in the middle (the agent). All it is supposed to do for now is, on pressing the up key, move the agent up and collect a $-sign.
'''

import tkinter as tk

class PlayGame:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.history=[] #Will contain the move history. Each element is a quadruple consisting of the state,action,reinforcement,new state.
    
    self.root=tk.Tk()
    for i in range(27):
        for j in range(27):
                tk.Label(self.root,text='$',height=1,width=3).grid(row=i,column=j)
    self.I=[14,14]
    tk.Label(self.root,text='I',height=1,width=3).grid(row=14,column=14)
    self.root.bind('<KeyPress>',self.onKeyPress)
    self.root.mainloop()

def onKeyPress(self,event):
    if event.keysym in ['Up','Right','Down','Left']:
        if event.keysym=='Up':
            tk.Label(self.root,text='',height=1,width=3).grid(row=self.I[0],column=self.I[1])
            tk.Label(self.root,text='I',height=1,width=3).grid(row=self.I[0]+1,column=self.I[1])
            self.I[0]+=1
```

'''

It still doesn't work and again, something very weird happened: First, I accidentally had 'row=self.I[0],column=self.I[1]+1' instead of 'row=self.I[0]+1,column=self.I[1]'. The agent would then move to the right when I pressed the up key. After I corrected the mistake, it didn't move at all anymore. But that line can't really be the reason it is not working, can it? Does anyone have an idea why it worked initially, but suddenly not anymore?

Comment: This is a little too much code... Try to make a [example].

Comment: Well you don't really need the second part of the code. And the first part is not too long is it? But I can try to rewrite it tomorrow.

Comment: It works fine for me (fixing some missing parts like `self.vis()` and `self.get_data()`).  Did you print out something at the beginning of `move_agent()`, like `direction` so that you know the function is executed?

Comment: No but I checked after some arrow strikes where the agent was at and he was still at the starting position so it did not perform move_agent. But like I said it also worked for me before I changed the list (then it even worked once after I changed the list but not anymore after I deleted some spaces at the end of the code, actually. Really random. I have no idea how this can be?)

Comment: Ok, problem solved: I did not know I had to click on the window that pops up first in order for the key strokes to be recognized by tkinter lol. Is this really how it's supposed to be? Anyways, thanks to everyone for helping and sorry for the confusion.